# Video stream quality in kpbs using PHP

Tags: php, file-upload, ffmpeg, video-streaming, video-encoding

I am working on a web application where to get the video streaming quality in kbps I am using PHP. I upload MP4 video and need to convert them to 1800kbps, 800kbps and 1000kbps videos.

I have searched the Internet for this but couldn't find any resource.

What do I need to do to measure video streaming quality ?

**How can I do this in PHP ?**

Comment: give some more explanation of problem.

Comment: simply i am uploading mp4 video and want to get three different bitrate video like HD,SD quality in php.